# getChildCount() returns incorrect number of children

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-custom-view

I have created a custom `TextView` with an X button, whose visibility are set to GONE when the button is clicked. Now I want to get the number of visible `TextViews` in the `LinearLayout`. Currently, I am getting the count of total TextViews inserted rather than the visible ones.

**Example:**

When I have 2 TextViews, getChildCount() gives 2
but if I delete one `TextView` by clicking the X button, it still gives me 2. Why is this happening?

I have created something like this:

[image: It is a TextView]

The X here is a button whose onClick() will set the visibility of both `TextView` and the `Button` to GONE.

Comment: A view with visiiblity set to gone is still a child of the parent layout.

Comment: That is what my question is, how can I get the count of the visible children?

Comment: getChildCount will retruns 1 if you call removeView on the parent. Changing the visibility does not remove the child

Comment: Could you post your code here? Without it we couldn't come to a solution.

Comment: Fingered the cause here (solution included): https://stackoverflow.com/a/70056362/17472273

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I get the count of the visible children?

Well for that you need to iterate over the children of the view/layout and check the visibility. It is a simple loop:

```
// untested/pseudocode
int visibleChildren = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (layout.getChildAt(i).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        visibleChildren++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather late to problem posted. Don't think the answers addressed the problem correctly. A few years since the problem of "getChildCount under reporting visible items displayed" was reported, yet my research found no one had fingered out what was causing this problem surfacing in some circumstances.

I had the same problem recently which led me to investigate further. Here's my discovery.

Say if 9 items on RecyclerView are visible. Call getChildCount(). It should return 9, maybe 1 or 2 less/more depending on partially visible items at the top and bottom. This will be the result most of the time ... until the soft keyboard shows for some TextEdit input. If you call getChildCount() about 500 msecs after the method call that led to showing the keyboard, the result will be less than 9. It will be the count of items unobstructed by the keyboard view. Weird, even though user didn't change the displayed contents of the RecyclerView. What's weird too is that even after the keyboard is dismissed, and all 9 items are again visible, calling getChildCount() will still return the incorrect under count! This happened with Android 11, and presumably with pre-11s (didn't test with post-11s).

A clue to solving this is the method RecyclerView.postInvalidateDelayed. If you really need to have the correct getChildCount number to work with, do something like this (after the keyboard is dismissed):

```
myRecyclerView.invalidate();
myRecyclerView.postDelayed(myRunnable, 200);
```

Subtle problem!