# how do i retrieve the value of all checkBox in the RecyclerView?

Tags: java, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

The data succesfully added to the firebase,
however it only send 3 data of recyclerView.

based on what chatGpt
since only 3 recyclerView fit in screen,thats why only 3 succesfully retrieve

here is the code

```
public void submitButtonFunction(){
    submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(date!=null) {
                DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.getReference()
                        .child("Subject")
                        .child(courseCode)
                        .child("attendance")
                        .child(date);
                List<String> selectedCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
                boolean anyCheckBoxChecked = false;
                Log.d("Date", date);
                for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                    CheckBox attendCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.attendCheckBox);
                    CheckBox absentCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.absentCheckBox);
                    CheckBox excuseCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.excuseCheckBox);

                    if (attendCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                        selectedCheckBoxes.add("Attend");
                        anyCheckBoxChecked = true;
                    } else if (absentCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                        selectedCheckBoxes.add("Absent");
                        anyCheckBoxChecked = true;
                    } else if (excuseCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                        selectedCheckBoxes.add("Excuse");
                        anyCheckBoxChecked = true;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(studentAttendance.this, "Please Check All the checkboxes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        selectedCheckBoxes.add("Not Checked");
                    }
                    String tempNameMatric = list.get(i).getStudentMatricNo() + " " + list.get(i).getStudentName() ;
                    dateRef.child(tempNameMatric).setValue(selectedCheckBoxes.get(i))
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    Toast.makeText(studentAttendance.this, "Succesful submit attendance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });

                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(studentAttendance.this, "Please Enter Date Of Attendance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

i have tried
-change the loop condition `i < list.size()`
-Based on chatGpt

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    subject currentSubject = list.get(i);
    CheckBox attendCheckBox = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
                                .itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendCheckBox);
    CheckBox absentCheckBox = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
                                .itemView.findViewById(R.id.absentCheckBox);
    CheckBox excuseCheckBox = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
                                .itemView.findViewById(R.id.excuseCheckBox);
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: i want to retrieve all data from the checkbox in recyclerView through for loop.
however what i got only 3 data eventho its supposed to be more than 3.

Answer (score 0):

try insted of

```
 for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
// all the logic was here
}
```

the above will only count and returns the number of child views currently attached to the RecyclerView ,which is pretty much you have on screen .

use

```
for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount(); i++) {
    // all of the code remains in here as you have
}
```

read more on it [recyclerview-getchildcount-is-returning-different-number-of-child-everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147000/recyclerview-getchildcount-is-returning-different-number-of-child-everytime)

EDIT:

for

> null pointer Process: com.example.collegesystem, PID: 13229
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
> object reference

1st just wrap the code in `if(date!=null)/else` to ensure not to null view is passed further.

and i place of `recyclerView.getChildAt(i);` try with `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)`

```
public void submitButtonFunction(){
  submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
  submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if(date!=null) {
              DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.getReference()
                      .child("Subject")
                      .child(courseCode)
                      .child("attendance")
                      .child(date);
              List<String> selectedCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
              boolean anyCheckBoxChecked = false;
              Log.d("Date", date);
              for (int i = 0; i <  recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount(); i++) {
                  View view =recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)//recyclerView.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(i) // recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                  if (view != null) {
                  CheckBox attendCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.attendCheckBox);
                  CheckBox absentCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.absentCheckBox);
                  CheckBox excuseCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.excuseCheckBox);

                  if (attendCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                      selectedCheckBoxes.add("Attend");
                      anyCheckBoxChecked = true;
                  } else if (absentCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                      selectedCheckBoxes.add("Absent");
                      anyCheckBoxChecked = true;
                  } else if (excuseCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                      selectedCheckBoxes.add("Excuse");
                      anyCheckBoxChecked = true;
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(studentAttendance.this, "Please Check All the checkboxes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      selectedCheckBoxes.add("Not Checked");
                  }
                  String tempNameMatric = list.get(i).getStudentMatricNo() + " " + list.get(i).getStudentName() ;
                  dateRef.child(tempNameMatric).setValue(selectedCheckBoxes.get(i))
                          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                              @Override
                              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                  Toast.makeText(studentAttendance.this, "Succesful submit attendance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                              }
                          });

              }else{
                Toast.makeText(studentAttendance.this, "Please Check view passed it could be null recyclerView.getChildAt(i) at i="+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }}
          }else{
              Toast.makeText(studentAttendance.this, "Please Enter Date Of Attendance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: i have tried change it and got null pointer

Process: com.example.collegesystem, PID: 13229
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: try the edit if did not works try by `recyclerView.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)`.let me know

Comment: I have tried it and still got null pointer,
then i tried asking chatGpt again and the bug is fixed, however i do not understand how and why it was fixed
- i touch 3 class, which is adapter,studentAttendance and subject

Comment: are you still getting any error?

Comment: Not anymore, but now new bug appears. Its probably logical of my if else i think