# Does getChildCount counts invisible/gone views as well?

Tags: android

I'm doing a "getChildCount" in LinearLayout.

I have a few visibility "GONE" views inside it.

Will they be counted as well?

I want to count only visible views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they will be counted. If you want to count only visible views, I would suggest the following:

```
int numVisibleViews = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
     if (layout.getChildAt(i).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
         numVisibleViews++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It counts **all** the views even if the view is set to gone. If you want to count the visible ones please read this post solution:

[Android : getChildCount() returning incorrect number of Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526350/android-getchildcount-returning-incorrect-number-of-children)

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation does not state that it only counts visible view ,it may be erroneous to conclude that it return the number of visible items .

> int getChildCount ()
>
> Returns the number of children in the group.

Using following code you get the total number of visible items in the layout .

```
int cnt=0;
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
               cnt++;
}
```